Facing issue as Could not initialize class com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JacksonUtil
We recently upgraded from spark 2.4.7 to 3.4.1 and hadoop 2.10.1 to 3.3.3.
Using hibernate-tyeps-52 dependency 2.0.0.
<groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version> 


Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JacksonUtil

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:825)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:783)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:717)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:608)

Class exist in library. Image attached.
Tried upgrading version for hibernate-types-52 to 2.20.1 ended in multiple failure.
The issue started after hadoop upgrade with spark upgrade api was working.
